# Validation of viewstate MAC failed - load balance environment

Tags: asp.net

My site is hosted on a web farm which in load balancing (total of 4 server) environment but
some of my client is encountering below error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by
a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration
specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm.
AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

**Description**: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web
request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it
originated in the code.

**Exception Details**: System.Web.HttpException: Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this
application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration
specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a
cluster.
```

However, Each of my four sites are having the below machinekey in the web.config file but still encountering the issue.

```
<machineKey
    validationKey="3B1107F98F6E4ECD868C929C0826C3845058F39B5113CD7E676170F4DBE4D65D83C65BCB166FFFB7F2749214C0CA503D04A956C1681F56C63A2B5D9F5F4B04FC"
    decryptionKey="3565248537BB78D03CCA78A2E8C757451EDCFD3D7AAE6199420FEE692158B37F"
    validation="SHA1" decryption="AES"
    />
```

Any advise? thanks

Answer (score -1):

I am taking it from here [Validation of viewstate MAC failed- Server Error in '/' Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181590/validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed-server-error-in-application).

```
<pages enableEventValidation="false" viewStateEncryptionMode="Never">
```

> The problem with the above solution is that you sacrifice some
>   security. The next "quick fix" is to add the following to the
>   web.config, but there are drawbacks to this as well:

```
<pages enableViewStateMac="false">
```

Both the above code can solve your problem.

Comment: Both suggestions are ok for development environment, but not recommended in production.