# Validation of viewstate MAC failed Error on Azure Web App

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

We are getting `Validation of viewstate MAC failed` error on an ASP.net application hosted on Azure as a Web App. This problem generally happens when the app is idle for a long time and then an action is performaed using Viewstate. In general on-premise servers, we can fix this by adding `machineKey` in `web.config` file. In case of Azure, even after adding `machineKey` in `web.config` file, the problem persists

Please advise what am I missing or how can I fix this isuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to add the following code to the `web.config`:

```
<pages enableEventValidation="false" viewStateEncryptionMode="Never">
```

Here is a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181590/validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed-server-error-in-application) you could refer to .

For more details about resolving view state message authentication code (MAC) errors, please refer to this [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/2915218/resolving-view-state-message-authentication-code-mac-errors).

Comment: can you explain what would this attribute do?

Comment: please refer to this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tom/2008/03/14/validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed-error/).