# How to avoid a 'Validation of viewstate MAC failed' error when changing a form's action with the ASP.NET view engine?

Tags: asp.net, http-post, httprequest

I'm having an issue in sending parameters and open a new window via a POST request.

Simply put, I have the following form defined:

```
<form method="post" action="default.aspx" id="ctl01">
```

I dynamically define/set hidden fields and set, target to `_blank` and change the action to a different file.

```
document.forms[0].setAttribute("target", "_blank");
document.forms[0].action = "NewDirectory/NewFile.aspx";  // causes the error
$('<input>').attr({
    type: 'hidden',
    id: 'Command1',
    name: 'DoSomething'
}).appendTo('form');

document.forms[0].submit();
```

When I set the new action and submit, I get the following error:

> Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a
>   Web Farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies
>   the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot
>   be used in a cluster.

I have read other [relate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349118/validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed-if-this-application-is-hosted-by-a-web-far) posts, however, on an enterprise application, messing around with the machine config on clients' systems just to make this one feature work is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Make `enableviewstate=false`
If you have defined `runat=server` for the form tag remove it and check